# Is this the best way to add an extra dimension to a numpy array in one line of code?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, reshape

If k is an numpy array of an arbitrary shape, so `k.shape = (s1, s2, s3, ..., sn)`, and I want to reshape it so that `k.shape` becomes `(s1, s2, ..., sn, 1)`, is this the best way to do it in one line?

```
k.reshape(*(list(k.shape) + [1])
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's easier like this:

```
k.reshape(k.shape + (1,))
```

But if all you want is to add an empty dimension at the end, you should use `numpy.newaxis`:

```
import numpy as np
k = k[..., np.newaxis]
```

or

```
k = k[..., None]
```

(See the [documentation on slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [numpy.expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

```
In [4]: import numpy as np                                                          

In [5]: a = [1,2,3,4]                                                                              

In [6]: np.expand_dims(a, axis=1)                                                                  
Out[6]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Comment: NOTE: np.reshape is faster than np.expand_dims.