# Broadcasting in Python with permutations

Tags: python, matlab, vectorization, broadcasting, permute

I understand that `transpose` on an `ndarray` is intended to be the equivalent of matlab's `permute` function however I have a specific usecase that doesn't work simply. In matlab I have the following:

```
C = @bsxfun(@times, permute(A,[4,2,5,1,3]), permute(B, [1,6,2,7,3,4,5])
```

where A is a 3D tensor of shape NxNxM and B is a 5D tensor of shape NxNxMxPxP. The above function is meant to vectorize looped kronecker products. I'm assuming that Matlab is adding 2 singleton dimensions for both A and B which is why it's able to rearrange them. I'm looking to port this code over to Python <strike>but I don't think it has the capability of adding these extra dimensions.</strike>. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835121/is-this-the-best-way-to-add-an-extra-dimension-to-a-numpy-array-in-one-line-of-c) which successfully adds the extra dimensions however the broadcasting is not working the same matlab's `bsxfun`. I have attempted the obvious translation (yes I am using numpy for these `ndarray`'s and functions):

```
A = A[...,None,None]
B = B[...,None,None]
C = transpose(A,[3,1,4,0,2])*transpose(B,[0,5,1,6,2,3,4])
```

<strike>and I get the following error:</strike>

```
return transpose(axes)
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

My first guess is to do a `reshape` on A and B to add in those singleton dimensions?

I now get the following error:

```
mults = transpose(rho_in,[3,1,4,0,2])*transpose(proj,[0,5,1,6,2,3,4])
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,9,1,9,8) (9,1,9,1,8,40,40)
```

EDIT: Amended my question to be less about adding singleton dimensions but more about correctly broadcasting this matlab multiplication in python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The huge difference between MATLAB and numpy is that the former uses column-major format for its arrays, while the latter row-major. The corollary is that implicit singleton dimensions are handled differently.

Specifically, MATLAB explicitly ignores trailing singleton dimensions: `rand(3,3,1,1,1,1,1)` is actually a `3x3` matrix. Along these lines, you can use `bsxfun` to operate on two arrays if their *leading* dimensions match: `NxNxM` is implicitly `NxNxMx1x1`  which is compatible with `NxNxMxPxP`.

Numpy, on the other hand, [allows implicit singletons *up front*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules). You need to `permute` your arrays in a way that their *trailing* dimensions match up, for instance shape `(40,40,9,1,9,1,8)` with shape `(1,9,1,9,8)`, and the result should be of shape `(40,40,9,9,9,9,8)`.

Dummy example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> (np.random.rand(40,40,9,1,9,1,8)+np.random.rand(1,9,1,9,8)).shape
(40, 40, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8)
```

Note that what you're trying to do can probably be done using [`numpy.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). I suggest taking a closer look at that. An example of what I mean: from your question I gathered that you want to perform this: take elements `A[1:N,1:N,1:M]` and `B[1:N,1:N,1:M,1:P,1:P]` and construct a new array `C[1:N,1:N,1:N,1:N,1:M,1:P,1:P]` such that

```
C[i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7] = A[i2,i4,i5]*B[i1,i3,i5,i6,i7]
```

(your specific index order might vary). If this is correct, you can indeed use `numpy.einsum()`:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(3,3,2)
>>> b = np.random.rand(3,3,2,4,4)
>>> np.einsum('ijk,lmkno->limjkno',a,b).shape
(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4)
```

Two things should be noted, though. Firstly, the above operation will be very memory-intense, which should be expected for cases of vectorization (where you usually win CPU time at the expense of memory need). Secondly, you should seriously consider rearranging the data model when you port your code. The reason that broadcasting works differently in the two languages is intricately connected to the column-major/row-major difference. This also implies that in MATLAB you should work with *leading* indices first, since `A(:,i2,i3)` corresponds to a contiguous block of memory, while `A(i1,i2,:)` does not. Conversely, in numpy `A[i1,i2,:]` is contiguous, while `A[:,i2,i3]` is not.

These considerations suggest that you should set up the logistics of your data such that vectorized operations preferably work with leading indices in MATLAB and trailing indices in numpy. You could still use `numpy.einsum` to perform the operation itself, however your dimensions should be in a different (possibly reverse) order compared to MATLAB, at least if we assume that both versions of the code use an optimal setup.

Comment: Would it be possible to contact you with a direct message of some kind to expand on this topic (specifically the uses of `einsum`)? I feel like my further questions would be too specific to be relevant here.

Comment: @Mike unfortunately Stack Overflow explicitly discourages off-site endeavours:) I can see your concern about being on topic, but you should either leave a comment here (if it's very closely related and simple), ask a new question (if it seems big enough to merit a full question), or come join us in chat in [the MATLAB room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/chatlab-and-talktave) or the [python one](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: Maybe that should be `np.einsum('ijk,lmkno->ljmikno',A,B)` instead because of that `(2,1,3)` in `permute(A...)`?

Comment: @Divakar aaah sorry, I forgot to leave a note here that [we continued the discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123027/throwaway-room-for-porting-vectorized-stuff-to-python) :S We did reach your conclusion `einsum`-wise, I believe:)

Comment: Ah if OP is looking for some reductions, probably `einsum` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your MATLAB code, you have -

```
C = bsxfun(@times, permute(A,[4,2,5,1,3]), permute(B, [1,6,2,7,3,4,5])
```

So, in essence -

```
B : 1 , 6 , 2 , 7 , 3 , 4 , 5 
A : 4 , 2 , 5 , 1 , 3
```

Now, in MATLAB we had to borrow singleton dimensions from higher ones, that's why all that trouble of bringing in dims `6`, `7` for `B` and dims `4` `5` for `A`.

In NumPy, we bring in those explicitly with [`np.newaxis`/None](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis). Thus, for NumPy, we could put it like so -

```
B : 1 , N , 2 , N , 3 , 4 , 5 
A : N , 2 , N , 1 , 3 , N , N
```

, where `N` represents new axis. Please notice that we were need to put in new axes at the end  for `A` to push forward other dimension for alignment. In constrast, this happens in MATLAB by default.

Making that `B` looks easy enough with as the dimensions seem to be in order and we just need to add in new axes at appropriate places - `B[:,None,:,None,:,:,:]`.

Creating such `A` doesn't look straight-forward. Ignoring `N's` in `A`, we would have - `A : 2 , 1 , 3`. So, the starting point would be permuting dimensions and then add in those two new axes that were ignored - `A.transpose(1,0,2)[None,:,None,:,:,None,None]`.

Thus far, we have -

```
B (new): B[:,None,:,None,:,:,:]
A (new): A.transpose(1,0,2)[None,:,None,:,:,None,None]
```

In NumPy, we can skip the leading new axes and trailing non-singleton dims. So, we could simplify like so -

```
B (new): B[:,None,:,None]
A (new): A.transpose(1,0,2)[:,None,...,None,None]
```

The final output would be multiplication between these two extended versions -

```
C = A.transpose(1,0,2)[:,None,...,None,None]*B[:,None,:,None]
```

**Runtime test**

I believe @Andras's post meant the equivalent `np.einsum` implementation to be something like : `np.einsum('ijk,lmkno->ljmikno',A,B)`.

```
In [24]: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(10,10,10))
    ...: B = np.random.randint(0,9,(10,10,10,10,10))
    ...: 

In [25]: C1 = np.einsum('ijk,lmkno->ljmikno',A,B)

In [26]: C2 = A.transpose(1,0,2)[:,None,...,None,None]*B[:,None,:,None]

In [27]: np.allclose(C1,C2)
Out[27]: True

In [28]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,lmkno->ljmikno',A,B)
10 loops, best of 3: 102 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit A.transpose(1,0,2)[:,None,...,None,None]*B[:,None,:,None]
10 loops, best of 3: 78.4 ms per loop

In [30]: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(15,15,15))
    ...: B = np.random.randint(0,9,(15,15,15,15,15))
    ...: 

In [31]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,lmkno->ljmikno',A,B)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.76 s per loop

In [32]: %timeit A.transpose(1,0,2)[:,None,...,None,None]*B[:,None,:,None]
1 loop, best of 3: 1.36 s per loop
```

Comment: I can confirm that indeed that's what I meant with `einsum`:)