# Convert elements of a Numpy array to lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a numpy array, which might look something like this

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

I would like to convert it to have one extra dimension, as such:

```
[[[1] 
  [2]]
 [[3]
  [4]]]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17835121/7207392 ?

Comment: Or, if you literally want what your title says: `np.vectorize(lambda x: [x], otypes='O')(<your_array>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.newaxis` and `tolist`:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
a[:, :, np.newaxis].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[[1], [2]], [[3], [4]]]
```